# TYPO3 7 tx_form with captcha

Tags: forms, typo3, captcha, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I'am trying to implement the captcha extension to my tx_form. 
The form is working correctly and the captcha code with an input field is displayed fine.

I'am not exactly sure where this needs to go and when the function is fired:

```
$response = GeneralUtility::_GP('captchaResponse');
    if (\ThinkopenAt\Captcha\Utility::checkCaptcha($response)) {
      // Captcha valid
      ...
    } else {
      // Captcha invalid
      ...
    }
```

My form so far:

```
enctype = multipart/form-data
method = post
prefix = tx_form
confirmation = 0
postProcessor {

        recipientEmail = someMail
        senderEmail = someMail
    }
10 = TEXTLINE
10 {
    type = text
    name = 2
    required = required
    label {
        value = Name:*
    }
}
20 = TEXTLINE
20 {
    type = text
    name = 3
    required = required
    label {
        value = E-Mail-Adresse:*
    }
}
30 = TEXTLINE
30 {
    type = text
    name = 4
    required = required
    label {
        value = Telefon:*
    }
}
40 = TEXTLINE
40 {
    type = text
    name = 5
    required = required
    label {
        value = Firma:*
    }
}
50 = TEXTLINE
50 {
    type = text
    name = 6
    required = required
    label {
        value = Funktion:*
    }
}
60 = TEXTLINE
60 {
    type = text
    name = 8
    required = required
    label {
        value = PLZ:*
    }
}
70 = TEXTLINE
70 {
    type = text
    name = 9
    required = required
    label {
        value = Ort:*
    }
}
80 = TEXTAREA
80 {
    cols = 40
    rows = 5
    name = 7
    required = required
    label {
        value = Ihr Anliegen:*
    }
}
100 = TEXTBLOCK
100 {
    text (
<img style="width:200px; height:auto;" src="/index.php?eID=captcha" />
 <input type="text" size=30 name="captchaResponse" value="">
    )
}
105 = SUBMIT
105 {
    name = 10
    type = submit
    value = Senden
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement an own finisher for that. I would recommend to use https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/pxa_form_enhancement/ or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Do you know any plugins without the google api?